# Read GPS coordinates and velocity in ECEF

Tags: android, gps, coordinates, velocity

Is it possible in android to read out the GPS coordinates and velocity in ECEF.

I'd like to have a velocity vector (x, y, z), like in standard GPS modules available?

Cheers,
Silvan

Answer (score 0):

No, the Android APIs only provide WGS84 positions, and there are no ECEF<->WGS84 functions in them. Nothing in the Google APIs for Android either.

So you need to implement this part yourself, maybe following this Wikipedia entry : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system#From_geodetic_to_ECEF